# Get record between two dates using mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to get the data between a date. Am having some record with from and to date. Now i want to check that record using a date.

```
Employee  Leave_from_date  Leave_to_date Leave_Type
001       06-10-2012       07-10-2012    Casual
```

I want use the select statement like this

```
 Select * from leave_request where fldempid=001 as L on fldfromdate
     >= 06-10-2012 and fldtodate<='06-10-2012'
```

if am using 07-10-2012 means the above record displayed again.

Please help me to create this...

Comment: There are already many related questions in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse the usual position of values and columns in a `between` clause:

```
select * 
from leave_request 
where fldempid = 001
and '06-10-2012' between fldfromdate and fldtodate
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
SELECT Employee, Leave_from_date, Leave_to_date, Leave_Type 
FROM  leave_request 
WHERE fldempid = 001 AND 
      DATE('06-10-2012') between fldfromdate and fldtodate
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to convert the dates over to unix timestamps first so you can safely compare using the `<=` `>=` operators

e.g

```
SELECT
Employee, Leave_Type  
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(fldfromdate) AS Leave_from_date, 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(fldtodate) as Leave_to_date 
FROM 
leave_request
where 
fldempid=001 as L on 
Leave_from_date>=1349481600 and Leave_to_date<=1349481600;
```

Haven't tried the above but should work with some tweeking...